# How to substitute a string in batch script?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

My arqtext.txt has the following dataset:

```
A,B,C,
(123 or 456) and (789 or 012),1,5,
(456 or 654) and (423 or 947),3,6,
(283 or 335) and (288 or 552),2,56,
```

I want to change the 1st column of the last 3 rows to a new string set in the script, with the result like:

```
A,B,C,
roi1,1,5,
roi2,3,6,
roi3,2,56,
```

But my code only output the header "A,B,C,":

```
@echo off 
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion EnableExtensions

set roi1="(123 or 456) and (789 or 012)"
set roi2="(456 or 654) and (423 or 947)"
set roi3="(283 or 335) and (288 or 552)"

set /p "header="<"arqtext.txt"
echo %header%>arqtextnovo.txt

for /f "skip=1 tokens=1,* delims=," %%a in ("arqtext.txt") do (
    if %%a=="roi1" (
        echo roi1,%%b>>arqtextnovo.txt
    )
    if %%a=="roi2" (
        echo roi2,%%b>>arqtextnovo.txt
    )
    if %%a=="roi3" (
        echo roi3,%%b>>arqtextnovo.txt
    )
)
rem EXIT /B
pause>nul
```

Comment: ```%%a``` is never going to ```==``` ```"roi1"```, ```"roi2"```, or ```"roi3"```. Not least because you already told us that it will be ```"(123 or 456) and (789 or 012)"```, ```"(456 or 654) and (423 or 947)"```, and ```"(283 or 335) and (288 or 552)"```. Perhaps you should be using the variables you defined instead! ```if "%%~a" == %roi1%```, ```if "%%~a" == %roi2%```, and ```if "%%~a" == %roi3%```. Then you'd need to ```echo``` ```%roi1%,%%b```, ```%roi2%,%%b``` and ```%roi3%,%%b```, or ```!roi1!,%%b```, ```!roi2!,%%b``` and ```!roi3!,%%b```.

Comment: Please however be very careful with the positioning of your redirection handles. Use either ```>>arqtextnovo.txt echo...``` or this syntax instead, ```(echo %roi1%,%%b)>>arqtextnovo.txt```. The former would probably be simpler for you.

Comment: In addition to the comments already posted, `set roi1="(123 or 456) and (789 or 012)"` will **include** the `"` in the value set. You need to use `set "roi1=(123 or 456) and (789 or 012)"` and then `if "%%a"=="%roi1%".

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I would do it:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "roi[(123 or 456) and (789 or 012)]=1"
set "roi[(456 or 654) and (423 or 947)]=2"
set "roi[(283 or 335) and (288 or 552)]=3"

set /P "header=" < "arqtext.txt"

> arqtextnovo.txt (

   echo %header%

   for /f "usebackq skip=1 tokens=1,* delims=," %%a in ("arqtext.txt") do (
       echo roi!roi[%%a]!,%%b
   )

)

rem EXIT /B
pause>nul
```

- The `for /F` command requires "usebackq" option if the filename is enclosed in quotes. Otherwise, it process the literal string enclosed in quotes.
- It is more efficient to (redirect the whole output) > to a file, instead of append >> every new line. This also avoid the problems of redirect lines that ends in numbers.
- If you have several values and want to select a result value based on the first one, it is much simpler and more efficient to use an *array* instead of test each individual value.

Let's suppose this method:

```
set /P "selector=Enter selector: "
if "%selector%" equ "nine" set result=9
if "%selector%" equ "seven" set result=7
if "%selector%" equ "five" set result=5
```

Instead, you may define an array called "value":

```
set "value[nine]=9"
set "value[seven]=7"
set "value[five]=5"
```

... and then directly get the result value this way:

```
set "result=!value[%selector%]!"
```

The same method is used in this code. However, you have not specified what happen if the input value is not one of the array elements.

For a further description on array management in Batch files, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990)